# PHP Get data from SOAP Web Service

Tags: php, soap

I have problem with SOAP Web Service and PHP. I try connect to the server and get data using one of method. I need to search a results by "NIP" value.
First of all, my code is:

```
$wsdl = 'https://datastoretest.ceidg.gov.pl/CEIDG.DataStore/Services/NewDataStoreProvider.svc?singleWsdl';
$data = array(
    "AuthToken" => "xxx",
    "NIP" => "6332212511"
);
$soap = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('trace' => true, 'exception' => true));
$response = $soap->__soapCall("GetMigrationDataExtendedAddressInfo", $data);
print_r($resopnse);
```

And the error looks like

> SoapFault exception: [a:DeserializationFailed] Program formatujący
>   zgłosił wyjątek podczas próby deserializacji komunikatu: Wystąpił błąd
>   podczas deserializacji treści komunikatu żądania dla operacji
>   „GetMigrationDataExtendedAddressInfo”. Oczekiwano końcowego elementu
>   „Body” z przestrzeni nazw „http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/”.
>   Znaleziono element „param1” z przestrzeni nazw „”. Wiersz 2, pozycja
>   176.. in..

When i try:

```
$soap->__getTypes();
$soap->__getFunctions();
```

results is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => struct GetID {
 string AuthToken;
 dateTime DateFrom;
 dateTime DateTo;
 dateTime MigrationDateFrom;
 dateTime MigrationDateTo;
}
    [1] => struct GetIDResponse {
 string GetIDResult;
}
    [2] => struct GetMigrationDataExtendedAddressInfo {
 string AuthToken;
 ArrayOfstring NIP;
 ArrayOfstring REGON;
 ArrayOfstring NIP_SC;
 ArrayOfstring REGON_SC;
 ArrayOfstring Name;
 ArrayOfstring Province;
 ArrayOfstring County;
 ArrayOfstring Commune;
 ArrayOfstring City;
 ArrayOfstring Street;
 ArrayOfstring Postcode;
 dateTime DateFrom;
 dateTime DateTo;
 ArrayOfstring PKD;
 ArrayOfint status;
 ArrayOfstring UniqueId;
 dateTime MigrationDateFrom;
 dateTime MigrationDateTo;
}
    [3] => struct GetMigrationDataExtendedAddressInfoResponse {
 string GetMigrationDataExtendedAddressInfoResult;
}
    [4] => int char
    [5] => duration duration
    [6] => string guid
    [7] => struct ArrayOfstring {
 string string;
}
    [8] => struct ArrayOfint {
 int int;
}
)
Array
(
    [0] => GetIDResponse GetID(GetID $parameters)
    [1] => GetMigrationDataExtendedAddressInfoResponse GetMigrationDataExtendedAddressInfo(GetMigrationDataExtendedAddressInfo $parameters)
    [2] => GetIDResponse GetID(GetID $parameters)
    [3] => GetMigrationDataExtendedAddressInfoResponse GetMigrationDataExtendedAddressInfo(GetMigrationDataExtendedAddressInfo $parameters)
)
```

I have information about envelope and search results by "NIP" from documentation of this web service (but i don't know how to use it):

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/"
xmlns:arr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
 <soapenv:Header/>
 <soapenv:Body>
 <tem:GetMigrationDataExtendedAddressInfo>
 <tem:AuthToken>xxx</tem:AuthToken>
 <tem:NIP>
 <arr:string>6332212511</arr:string>
 </tem:NIP>
 </tem:GetMigrationDataExtendedAddressInfo>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

So what i do wrong? :(
Please help me with this issue.

Comment: I think it should be `$response = $soap->__soapCall("GetMigrationDataExtendedAddressInfo", array($data));`

Comment: Yes. It's working but response is "there is no such account". So, probably problem is with parameters sending as $data. AuthToken is OK, because service let me in.

Comment: Udało Ci się rozwiązać ten problem? Też dostaję komunikat 'Brak konta użytkownika'

Comment: Uderz do mnie na FB https://www.facebook.com/MatuszczykRyaN powysyłam CI źródło...bo rozpracowałem to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the fact that I have more and more private inquiries, I present a solution below. The code has been working for all people so far. If you have a problem with this code, you probably have something blocked / firewall / upgrade php to a newer version / check if you have soap by phpinfo() function :)

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
$arrLocales = array('pl_PL', 'pl','Polish_Poland.28592');
setlocale( LC_ALL, $arrLocales );
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Warsaw');
set_time_limit(0);

function XML2Array(SimpleXMLElement $parent) {
    $array = array();
    foreach ($parent as $name => $element) {
        ($node = & $array[$name])
            && (1 === count($node) ? $node = array($node) : 1)
            && $node = & $node[];
        $node = $element->count() ? XML2Array($element) : trim($element);
    }
    return $array;
}

$wsdl = 'https://datastore.ceidg.gov.pl/CEIDG.DataStore/services/NewDataStoreProvider.svc?singleWsdl';
$nip = array("1112223344");
$token = 'CEIDG_TOKEN';
$data = array(
    "AuthToken"  => $token,
    "NIP"        => $nip,
);

$soap = new SoapClient($wsdl);
$resp = $soap->__soapCall("GetMigrationDataExtendedAddressInfo",array($data));

$array = json_decode(json_encode($resp), true);

$wpis = $array['GetMigrationDataExtendedAddressInfoResult'];
$xml = simplexml_load_string($wpis);
$xml_array = unserialize(serialize(json_decode(json_encode((array) $xml), 1)));
print_R($xml_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Parameters:

> $params = array(
>       'AuthToken'=>'xxx',
>       'NIP'=>array($parameters));

Response:

> $response =
>   $soapclient->__soapCall("GetMigrationDataExtendedAddressInfo",
>   array($params));

Comment: Wiem wiem, już do tego doszedłem :) Ale dzięki za zainteresowanie.